# Why today i.e. 31st Aug is being called the First day of September series in trade market

Tags: stock-markets, money-market

I read this [post](https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/markets/closing-bell-nifty-ends-below-11700-on-day-1-of-september-series-sensex-mildly-lower-it-pharma-soar-2901071.html) today, on 31st Aug . Why does it mention today as 1st day of September series. Shouldn't tomorrow be the first day ?

I do not have much knowledge regarding this. I tried to google around this but nothing concrete came up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"September series" refers to futures and option contracts that will expire in September.  The context of the article implies that August 31st was the first day of trading for these.